# conversion of Array[dataframe] to dataframe in scala

Tags: arrays, apache-spark-sql, sequence, scala-collections

the following returns df1 as Array[DataFrame] or Array[Seq]
  val df1= df.rdd.collect.map(f => {return single data frame with new rows for each element of the object(encoder logic)})

Please suggest me how do I get DataFrame from df1.